# memove a masked array - python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, ctypes, memmove

I have a numpy array which contains no data values.  I mask those no data values so that they do not influence my calculations using:

```
    array = numpy.ma.masked_values(array, options['ndv'], copy=False)
```

I then use memmove to get the numpy array into a shared ctypes array using:

```
def ndarray_to_shmem(array):
    """ Converts a numpy.ndarray to a multiprocessing.Array object.

    The memory is copied, and the array is flattened.
    """
    arr = array.reshape((-1, ))
    data = RawArray(_numpy_to_ctypes[array.dtype.type], 
                                    arr.size)
    ctypes.memmove(data, array.data[:], len(array.data))
    return data
```

Which returns the following stack trace:

```
ctypes.memmove(data, array.data[:], len(array.data))
ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 2: <type 'exceptions.TypeError'>: wrong type
```

Is it possible to use memmove to move the masked array into a shared, ctypes array?

Comment: What exactly are you expecting to happen when you move the masked array? Are you hoping to get only the values that are not masked? Should the no-value entries be converted to nan?

Comment: Converted to NaN.  I will then convert back to the input's no data value after performing some calculation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First** of all, you need to change this line:

```
ctypes.memmove(data, array.data[:], len(array.data))
```

to look like this:

```
ctypes.memmove(data, array.data[:].ctypes.data, len(array.data))
```

**Second**, ctypes.memmove has no understanding of masked arrays. Instead, just make a copy with the masked areas set to nan:

```
masked = array.copy()
masked[array == options['ndv']] = np.nan

...

ctypes.memmove(data, masked.ctypes.data, len(masked))
```

Comment: Luke, why the first item?  Just stumbled onto the second via the numpy docs thanks to your initial comment.  Thanks!

Comment: The requirement to use array.ctypes.data is because ctypes has no understanding of numpy arrays (given a numpy array, ctypes does not know how to locate the array data it contains). The attribute array.ctypes.data is just a pointer to the memory array contained within, which ctypes is able to understand.